# How to install a syntax file for VIM on OS X

Tags: html, vim

I followed the instructions of a tutorial I read and downloaded the following file into *~/.vim/syntax*: [html5.vim](https://gist.github.com/rcmachado/256840/raw/6a1ce1c894236adc5859d4710fda3df9ea750ac6/html5.vim).

However, when I opened up vim I didn't see any of my HTML5 keywords highlighted. I had to type `:source ~/.vim/syntax/html5.vim` to see the changes take effect. (For what it's worth, I had to create this directory myself - it didn't exist beforehand.)

Why didn't vim automatically detect this file? Do I have to add `source /path/to/syntax.vim` to *.vimrc* every time I want to include a new syntax file?

**Edit:**

Figured out the answer. I moved html5.vim into *~/.vim/after/syntax/html/html5.vim*. It now knows to add these changes for html filetypes.

Comment: It's great that you've found a solution. Please add it below as an answer to your question and accept it, so that others who have your problem will be able to see from the search interface that your problem was sovled.